# ZeroMQ on Heroku

Tags: heroku, zeromq, akka-zeromq

Why doesn't it exist on Heroku?

I want to use Akka and a distributed queues system for actors to communicate on different dynos. RabbitMQ doesn't seem to be the best option using Akka, because a lot of tricks are needed to seamlessly work with actors without concerning about the underlying queues.

Nevertheless, the best option seems to be [Durable Mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/durable-mailbox.html) but with RabbitMQ: [akka-amqp-mailbox](https://github.com/drexin/akka-amqp-mailbox). I still have to set it up first though.

What other options do you consider that provide a seamless underlying queues system on Heroku with Akka?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Heroku Vulcan](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan) to build and run it yourself. This is what I do whenever I run into something that Heroku doesn't support OOTB. And, "why doesn't it exist"? Because you haven't built it yet! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: I managed to build it after applying this hack (https://github.com/heroku/vulcan/issues/51), but I don't know how to use the result. This tutorial (http://goo.gl/S0WaW) says we should vendor the app, but I can't find an bin/executable to run it and thus start the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can "use" it by incorporating it into a buildpack, or by pulling it in during boot (as in, have your Procfile run a script that downloads the binaries produced from your vulcan build)

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to a tutorial / doc doing it? I couldn't find something to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official Heroku APT buildpack to install *zmq* to your Heroku app.

Steps:

1) Add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt as a buildpack. Make sure it is added above/before build packs such as heroku/nodejs so dependencies can be met.

2) Add `Aptfile` file into the root of your repo with this content:

```
libzmq3-dbg
libzmq3-dev
libzmq3
```

3) Deploy