# zmq, zerorpc deployment on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, zeromq

I am trying to deploy ZMQ on Heroku with Node.js

I was able to compile ZMQ and get the libs inside my Node build,
however I cannot figure out how to setup the Heroku Environment, specifically NPM ZMQ package to search the right folder to find the libzmq files.

thus, stuck at ../binding.cc:28:17: warning: zmq.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you ever follow-up on this? What was the eventual outcome (before I explore any further the details of Heroku support for zmq - if I come across a solution or otherwise I shall provide an answer to this question myself).

Comment: For Ruby with Heroku tutorial, here is a link - http://www.hward.com/zeromq-on-heroku  This is likely similar to what would be required using NodeJS. Still checking..

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389265/zeromq-on-heroku/44555440#44555440

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZeroMQ on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389265/zeromq-on-heroku)